# Changing the values of a dict in lowercase ( values are code colors ) to be accepted as a color parametrer in plotly.graph.object

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

So, I'm trying to get the colors from the dictionary 'Disaster_type' to draw the markers in geoscatters depending of the type of disaster.

Basically, I want to reprensent in the graphic the natural diasasters with it's color code. eg; it's is a volcanic activity paint it 'orange'. I want to change the size of the marker as well depending of the magnitude of the disaster, but that's for another day.

here's the link of the dataset:  https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/brsdincer/all-natural-disasters-19002021-eosdis

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import pandas as pd
import plotly as plt

df = pd.read_csv('1900_2021_DISASTERS - main.csv')
df.head()
df.tail()
disaster_set = {disaster for disaster in df['Disaster Type']}
disaster_type = {'Storm':'aliceblue', 
 'Volcanic activity':'orange', 
 'Flood':'royalblue', 
 'Mass movement (dry)':'darkorange',
 'Landslide':'#C76114',
 'Extreme temperature':'#FF0000',
 'Animal accident':'gray55',
 'Glacial lake outburst':'#7D9EC0',
 'Earthquake':'#CD8C95',
 'Insect infestation':'#EEE8AA', 
 'Wildfire':'   #FFFF00', 
 'Fog':'#00E5EE', 
 'Drought':'#FFEFD5', 
 'Epidemic':'#00CD66    ', 
 'Impact':'#FF6347'}
# disaster_type_lower = {(k, v.lower()) for k, v in disaster_type.items()}
# print(disaster_type_lower)
# for values in disaster_type.values():
#     disaster_type[values] = disaster_type.lowercase()


fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(
    lon = df['Longitude'], 
    lat = df['Latitude'],
    text = df['Country'],
    mode = 'markers',
    marker_color = disaster_type_.values()
        )
  )             
fig.show()
```

I cant figure how, I've left in comments after the dict how I tried to do that.
It changes them to lowercase, but know I dont know hot to get them...My brain is completly melted

Comment: Where is your question? how can we help you ? :)

Comment: @Phoenix oh shit sorry, I want to show a color for each different type of natural disaster, that's why I made the dict in first place! My bad hahaha

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify exactly what you are looking for. Adding more details will keep from your question being closed, and increase the chances of others helping.

Comment: @AndrewGB cheers mate, I edited. It wasn't clear what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

- it's a simple case of [pandas map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)
- found data that appears same as yours on **kaggle** so have used that
- one type is unmapped *Extreme temperature* so used a `fillna("red")` to remove any errors
- **gray55** gave me an error so replaced it with RGB equivalent

```
import kaggle.cli
import sys
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# fmt: off
# download data set
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/brsdincer/all-natural-disasters-19002021-eosdis"
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + f"datasets download {urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path[1:]}".split(" ")
kaggle.cli.main()
zfile = ZipFile(f'{urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1]}.zip')
dfs = {f.filename: pd.read_csv(zfile.open(f)) for f in zfile.infolist()}
# fmt: on
df = dfs["DISASTERS/1970-2021_DISASTERS.xlsx - emdat data.csv"]

disaster_type = {
    "Storm": "aliceblue",
    "Volcanic activity": "orange",
    "Flood": "royalblue",
    "Mass movement (dry)": "darkorange",
    "Landslide": "#C76114",
    "Extreme temperature": "#FF0000",
    "Animal accident": "#8c8c8c",  # gray55
    "Glacial lake outburst": "#7D9EC0",
    "Earthquake": "#CD8C95",
    "Insect infestation": "#EEE8AA",
    "Wildfire": "   #FFFF00",
    "Fog": "#00E5EE",
    "Drought": "#FFEFD5",
    "Epidemic": "#00CD66    ",
    "Impact": "#FF6347",
}


fig = go.Figure(
    data=go.Scattergeo(
        lon=df["Longitude"],
        lat=df["Latitude"],
        text=df["Country"],
        mode="markers",
        marker_color=df["Disaster Type"].map(disaster_type).fillna("red"),
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[image]